# Threading and multiple exceptions

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, c++11

I understand that in a single threaded context, it is not possible to have two exceptions active at the same time and in such a case terminate would be called.

But what happens if a function which could possibly throw an exception be called from multiple threads. During such a multi threaded call, if the function starts throwing exception, is it ok to have multiple such exceptions active at the same time? or we have to handle the active exception before any other exception can be thrown?

Comment: Each threaded function activation is on a difference activation-stack. Each is handled in concurrence with the others (subject to locking on *your* part). An exception unwind on one thread is no more, or less, contentious with another thread than running *basic code* on said-threads concurrently.

Comment: Each thread can have an active exception. You just can't have the exception leave the thread.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'd have thought `uncaught_exceptions` refers only to the number of uncaught exceptions on the current thread - at least, that's my reading of n4259.

Comment: @ecatmur: You're right, that one is about recursive unwinding in a single thread -- never mind, comment removed (and the rational is in [N4152](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4152.pdf)).